# how to get CREATESTRUCT of a window?

Tags: c, winapi, window

I am trying to make a windows GUI application.

I declared some static variables in my window procedure function and initialized it in the `WM_CREATE` whose `lParam` is a pointer to the `CREATESTRUCT`. However, since these values are static, I can only make one instance of my window; if I make more the previous instances' data will be changed to the new datas.
Is there a way to access the `CREATESTRUCT` of a window after the `WM_CREATE` message so that I can solve this problem?

Comment: There is an MSDN article describing exactly this situation: [Managing Application State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381400(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save a pointer to a user-defined structure in `WM_CREATE` using either `SetWindowLongPtr` or `SetProp`, and retrieve it with the matching functions.

e.g.

```
case WM_CREATE:
    SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA, ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->lpCreateParams);
    break;

case <other messages>:
    MyData* pData = (MyData*)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA).
```

Some will argue that you shouldn't use `GWLP_USERDATA` and instead should reserve storage space in your window class; this is up to you. Using `SetProp`/`GetProp` is also a valid alternative.